# Obtaining a single item from firebase list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase allows you to query for a single value in a list if you know it's key. However it seems tricky to obtain a single value in a list if you don't have the key.

I've been able to retrieve the desired item, however the solution seems verbose and a bit hacky.

Heres my function:
(fbutil is my firebase url reference base)

```
function getCopy(number){
      var defer = $q.defer();
      var ref = fbutil.ref('copies').orderByChild("number").equalTo(number);
      ref.once("value",function(copySnap){
        if(!copySnap.exists()){
          defer.reject(null);
        }else{
          var listObj = copySnap.val();
          var list = Object.keys(listObj).map(function(copy){
              return listObj[copy]});
          defer.resolve(list[0]);
        }
      })
      return defer.promise;
    }
```

This code does work however I wonder if there is a better way to obtain the item. Is there a firebase function that I am missing? Or a cleaner way to extract the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function could be made a little simpler.

**With the Firebase 3 API:**

The [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) function returns a promise, so you don't need to create your own. And you could use the snapshot's [`forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) function to enumerate the children - returning `true` to short-circuit the enumeration after the first child:

```
function getCopy (number) {
  var ref = fbutil.ref('copies').orderByChild("number").equalTo(number);
  return ref.once("value").then(function (copiesSnap) {
    var result = null;
    copiesSnap.forEach(function (copySnap) {
      result = copySnap.val();
      return true;
    });
    return result;
  });
}
```

**With the Firebase 2 API:**

[`once`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) does not return a promise, but you could still use the snapshot's [`forEach`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html) function to enumerate the children - returning `true` to short-circuit the enumeration after the first child:

```
function getCopy (number) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var ref = fbutil.ref('copies').orderByChild("number").equalTo(number);
  ref.once("value", function (copiesSnap) {
    var result = null;
    copiesSnap.forEach(function (copySnap) {
      result = copySnap.val();
      return true;
    });
    defer.resolve(result);
  });
  return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing but 'once' needs two arguments, in this case "value" and a callback function. also when returning the 'once' function as if it was a promise it's always undefined. Unfortunately this isn't working for me..

Comment: The `successCallback` for `once` is optional. If it's not passed, it should return a promise. You are using Firebase 3, right?

Comment: Interesting, I'm using firebase 2 however, 2.2.2 according to my bower.json

Comment: Updated to include a Firebase 2 example.

Comment: Thanks that it much better then looking up the key each time!